# Oracle : how to optimise the SQL with multiple select subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, query-optimization, query-performance

TABLENAME : table

Columns :

```
Id | name | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | time
```

Query:

```
Select (case when select count(*) from s1 where s1.b1 = 1
                     then select top 1 from s1 where s1.b1 = 1 order by time desc
                     else s2.id 
             end) as COLUMNONE,
       (case when select count(*) from s1 where s1.b2 = 1
                       then select top 1 from s1 where s1.b2 = 1 order by time desc
                       else s2.name 
               end) as COLUMNTWO,
       (case when select count(*) from s1 where s1.b3 = 1
                       then select top 1 from s1 where s1.b3 = 1 order by time desc
                       else s2.c1 
             end) as COLUMNTHREE,
       (case when select count(*) from s1 where s1.b4 = 1
                     then select top 1 from s1 where s1.b4 = 1 order by time desc
                     else s2.c2 
             end) as COLUMNFOUR
 from 
     table s1, table s2
 where s1.id = s2.id;


s1 table records
uniqueId | Id | name | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | time
  a        12   abc    qw   tr   cd   hi    1    1    1    1    1
  b        13   abc    qw   tr   cd   hi    1    1    1    1    2
  c        14   abc    qw   tr   cd   hi    1    1    1    1    3
  d        12   null   null null cd   hi    1    0    0    0    4
  e        13   abcef  qw   tr   cd   hi    1    1    0    0    5
  f        14   null   null null cd   hi    1    0    0    0    6
  g        12   abcji  qwer trft cd   hi    1    1    1    0    7
  h        13   null   null null cd   hi    1    0    0    0    8
  i        14   abc    qw   tryr cdoi hi    1    0    1    1    9
  j        12   abc    qw   trqw cdpl hi    1    0    0    1    10
  k        13   abcij  qw   tr   cd   hi    1    1    0    0    11
  l        14   abc    qw   troi cd   hi    1    0    1    0    12

s2 table records will contain the latest records
 Id | name | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | time
 12   abc    qw   tr   cdpl hi    1    0    0    1    10
 13   abcij  qw   tr   cd   hi    1    1    0    0    11
 14   abc    qw   troi cd   hi    1    0    1    0    12



OUTPUT :
  Id(COLUMNONE) | name(COLUMNTWO)   | c1(COLUMNTHREE) | c2(COLUMNFOUR) | 
  12                abcji                   qw              trqw
  13                abcij                   qw              tr
  14                abc                     qw              tryr
```

Can somebody help me how to optimise, if I have multiple select sub-queries ?

Comment: A better way to phrase this question might be to show sample input data and the output you are expecting.

Comment: To me, this code looks pretty much invalid. Is it really Oracle? Which version? BTW, `select`s in `case` aren't compared to anything, there are parenthesis missing, how can that be a `select` (while it looks more like an `update`)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @Littlefoot I just posted some pseudocode of it. Hope my edited question would help you to suggest me with some solution

Comment: @Eyeself . . . Your "query" will not run in any database.  Hence, it seems really hard to optimize.  Syntax errors return really quickly.  You want to figure out how to do something.  I would recommend that you ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.